# How to call a method from another class to the class where the run method is present in java

Tags: java

Is there a way to call a method from another class to the class where the run method is present (without creating the object of the class with the run method)? I would like to know how the method addMouseListeners() call my mouseClicked() method located in the class where the run method is present. Please answer.

Comment: It is called via callback after you provide you `listener` object by interface.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking about the callback pattern.  [Wiki has some information and examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) you might be interested in.

In general, the callback pattern involves passing off an instance of a class which will have various methods on it called in response to some event.  Your mouse listener is a callback class instance, and the container you passed it to is generating mouse events and passing them to your mouse listener.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I believe this answers the question perfectly.

Comment: @TomášZíma "Perfectly"? It contains just a design pattern name an a link. This can be even considered a "link only" answer, which can be flagged for deletion.

Comment: Well: bad question, simple answer :)

Comment: @TomášZíma A bad question should result in a flag, not in a "link only" answer :D. But David already updated his answer, so it is ok now.